# mysql query + sprintf = injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

i always like to use other sanitazing methods (and prepared statments) but i am under certain conditions where the client doesn`t want me to change a single line from his original script (im only going to add a plugin)

im worried someone could exploit this by modifying the $POST values and he could blame me (like clients usually do):

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "POST");
$q = sprintf(ARQ, trim($POST_string));
$res = doexec($q);
DEFINE("ARQ", "INSERT INTO library (string) VALUES ('%s')");
```

i tried several combinations but all i could get was an error, no mysql inject
so, is this secure enough, as is?

Comment: Not safe at all. The `%s` does not escape the data. It just requires a string to be put in it's place. You need to either look at `PDO` / `mysqli` and use prepared statements or using `mysql_real_escape_string` on the value before placing it in the query.

Comment: Have you seen the [sprintf example in the mysql_query documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)?  Looks a lot simpler than what you posted, and injection safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `doexec` calls something that does not accept multiple commands chained with `;`? You could still use a subquery to insert passwords and other sensitive data from other tables (assuming the user can read back the data he saved - otherwise you can use a [timing attack](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blind_SQL_Injection#Timing_Attack)). If the filesystem security is as poor as that of the database access code, you can use SELECT INTO to create a php script you can execute.